# How to access Ubuntu files in Windows 7 while having dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I just installed Windows 7 along with Ubuntu 13.04. I have all my software dump in my Ubuntu partitions which I want to install in Windows 7. How can I access the Ubuntu partition so that I can copy my software files in Windows 7? I can't even see partition of Ubuntu.

Comment: Download `ext4 explorer` software to see the files in ubuntu partition.

Comment: Can i copy the software files also which i have on my Ubuntu download folder ??

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use Disk Internals Linux Reader for Windows. I too use it to access (read + copy) my Ubuntu files while using Windows OS.

[image]

Here is the link:

[Disk Internals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)

Comment: Can i copy the software files also which i have on my Ubuntu download folder ??

Comment: yes you can. Just give it a try.

Comment: Best solution I've found is Paragone ExtFS. It's professionally developed, tested on Windows 10 and seamlessly integrates with Windows at driver level (requires free registration).

Comment: Files can be saved using save option provided by the utility. It works with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 18.04.