# Can't access files on ubuntu from hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I recently spilled coffee on my laptop (that had both windows and ubuntu) and it won't work anymore. In an attempt to save the hard drive, I bought a hard drive enclosure and was able to access it, but the problem now is that I can only view the files on windows os. is there a way I can access my files saved on ubuntu?
I'm currently trying to access these files from a macOS.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?  Windows doesn't know how to deal with Unix file systems

Comment: Yes, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and also attach another USB backup disk drive, and drag files/folders over.

Comment: Try following answers from these questions 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/379356/how-to-access-ubuntu-files-in-windows-7-while-having-dual-boot
https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read ext4 partitions in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows)

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use Disk Internals Linux Reader on another laptop that uses Windows OS and I was able to access the library files on linux but couldn't find any of my own files.

Answer (score 0):

Plug the hard drive into a machine that either knows or uses the EXT4 file system.

Pretty sure macOS and other linux ditros can do this.

Comment: I'm now using macOS and can't find the files.

Comment: Is the drive mounted and everything?

Comment: I believe that yeah, since I'm able to find the files that were on windows.

Comment: I imagine the drive is separated into partitions then or something. Try having a look in GParted to make sure the partition you want is mounted and visible.

Comment: Got GParted and I can access the partition but none of files were there. I could find all other files like the python library files but non of my saved stuff were there. How can that be possible! Also thank you for you help, I appreciate it!

Comment: @arwa In case you might've hidden the files or directories, (assuming the partition is mounted) go into the partition via GUI and right click on the empty space. You might see a box called "Show hidden folders". Maybe that might help? Not sure.